# Show user details when we hover on userid

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to show full user details on userid hover.

like this example...how to achieve this..

[image]

I have to show the image and some details of user like username, real name, birthday etc

How can I do this?

Comment: the link does not show info into tooltips rather it use Modal dialog on hover of image.

Comment: Use some kind of popover like jQuery popover / bootstrap popover.

Comment: on mouseover event show the modal dialog and content of it would be the result from an ajax query to a php file. e.g. in your ajax query you will pass userid to get_result.php and in get_result.php you will fetch all data and will print it in proper html. I hope you get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.mouseover()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)  to trigger an ajax call to get your information and put it inside a pop-up.